# TFT display show command line, but not RetroPie GUI

Tags: display, retropie

I recently got this 3 inch TFT for my Pi : https://www.optimusdigital.ro/ro/raspberry-pi/2027-lcd-de-3-pentru-raspberry-pi-3.html
Problem is, after I installed the display, it only shows the command line. The RetroPie GUI and menu is only shown on the HDMI display.

I have RetroPie 4.3 installed on my Pi Zero. Any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

Does it start if you type "emulationstation" in the command line?
Also, have you followed any setup guides for the display?

Here's the one I followed for my TFT display: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/easy-install-2

Comment: I didn't try to type emulationstation.Also if you scrol down a bit on the link that i provided,there will be a guide that i followed.You may need to translate some words from romania.